# Does this custom compare method contain a logical error

Tags: java, android, sorting

In an android application, I have a list of locations. I need to sort them based on their distance with the user location. for that I implemented a custom comparator:

```
Collections.sort(houseList, new Comparator<HouseEntity>()
  {
     @Override
     public int compare(HouseEntity house1, HouseEntity house2)
     {
        if(userLocation == null) return 0;
        return (int) (userLocation.distanceTo(house1.location) - userLocation.distanceTo(house2.location));
     }
  });
```

It is working well on all the testings I made. However some users had a crash with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

After reading all the other same issues on SO I concluded that this error appears when there might be an error in the logic (for example we might get a>b and b>a in the same time). But I couldn't find any scenario to replicate that logic error.

What scenario could be causing this error? And how can I solve it?

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Are you sure the cast to `(int)` never overflows/underflows? Can you try `Double.compare(x, y)` instead?

Comment: Have you tried logging the results of the comparisons? What's the return type of the `distanceTo` method?

Comment: It seems that in those cases, some bad values are passed in?

Comment: @harism THe comparor use substruction to know the order of the distances. a_dist - b_dist will give a negative so a comes before b and so on. finally I will get a list sorted in the coorect order from the smallest distance to the biggest

Comment: @Youssef removed my comment as it made no sense at all. Sorry  :)

Comment: You would be better not to bother sorting the list if userLocation is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Peter Lawrey** said, you should use `Double.compare(x, y)` or `Float.compare(x, y)` instead of casting to int. Here the explanation:

Comparator MUST be transitive, i.e. whenever A == B and B == C, then also A == C. Lets imagine we have three points `A`, `B` and `C` with the distances to the user location 0.2, 0.4 and 1.3.

1. (int) (0.2 - 0.4) = (int) (-0.2) = 0 => `A == B`
2. (int) (0.4 - 1.3) = (int) (-0.9) = 0 => `B == C`
3. (int) (0.2 - 1.3) = (int) (-1.1) = -1 => `A < C`

As you can see the comparator is not transitive.

Answer (score 0):

If `userLocation == null` then `house1.equals(house2)` should give true.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: The `IllegalArgumentException` thrown with the given error message indicates that the `compare` method is not consistent with the `equals` method. I pointed out such a case, when this might happen, however until we see the implementation of `HouseEntity.equals()` we indeed cannot be sure whether this is the cause.